# Get working code back but maintaining a few changes

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, smartgit

I have a repository with two branch: `master` and `development`. Recently I added some code to `development` which broke my entire working site but in this same `commit & push` I fix a lot of things too. Is there any way to come back to working code but maintaining those fixes that work? I use SmartGit on Windows 7, the repos are hosted at Bitbucket.

**Add some extra information around SmartGit Logs**

[image]

Comment: So there is exactly one commit which you would like to drop? Should it be dropped only in `master` or in `development`, too? Are you using git-flow?

Comment: @mstrap I don't care to drop for both, right now I'm learning and yes it's a real project but I messed up so now I need to fix that before continue and no, I not using `git-flow` in depth I didn't know this side of Git at all just a few reads but nothing real til now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1 (many or already pushed commits)**

Using SmartGit's *Log* window, select the offending commit and invoke **Revert**.

**Approach 2 (few and only local commits)**

If the numbers of affected commits is small and all of them are not yet pushed, I would recommend to re-create `development` using SmartGit's *Log* window:

(1) **Checkout** the last known good commit on `development`. When doing so, SmartGit will ask you whether to create a new branch: confirm this and create e.g. `development-2`.

(2) **Cherry-Pick** all good commits from `development` to `development-2`. If there are conflicts, switch to the *Main* window and fix them in your working tree.

(3) Use **Add Branch** and (re-add) `development` to your current HEAD commit, i.e. `development` will be identical to `development-2` afterwards.

(4) **Check Out** `development` again and finally **Delete** `development-2`.

Comment: I added a image to the main topic where I show the SmartGit Logs window, in there the commit marked is the one I want to revert and it was made yesterday. Now I'm not sure about which commit to checkout, the one showed in parent (right side after avatar)? Any way to get the right commit?

Comment: The one below the selected commit.

Comment: Note, as you have quite a lot of commits, you could also use **Revert** on this single commit. It will result in a new commit doing exactly the reverse changes of your offending commit. This doesn't give you a clean history as the outlined approach, but will be faster.

Comment: I'll use revert since the other way is painful a lot of conflicts, let me try this instead